# running tests that use remote webdriver and connects to a selenium hub and node fails

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

## Overview:

I am trying to run a python script that uses webdriver.Remote using CHROME  browser in an ubuntu server. I have setup a selenium grid (a hub and a node) in the server and used systemd service files to run the hub and node AND xvfb as background processes. However, running the python file gives me a: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:`

#### More Details:

- Selenium server version: 3.4
- Chromedriver version: 2.29 (Already in /usr/local/bin - no problem running this)
- Geckodriver version: 0.15.0 (i am using chrome browser, but putting this here just in case you need it.
- i am already exporting DISPLAY :5 for xvfb
- checking netstat -tln shows that hub and node are running on ports 4444 and 5555
- i am automating the setup of the digital ocean servers via fabric. So how do i run the python script? I put the code INSIDE the digital ocean server, and run the code there
- please let me know if you need more details but when i check the logs of the NODE, i don't see any messages at all that a session has been created in the node

I've been creating fresh droplets and spent countless hours already debugging what is wrong.

## Code

#### For xvfb process:

```
[Unit]
Description=X Virtual Frame Buffer Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/Xvfb :5 -screen 0 1024x768x8

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### For selenium HUB:

```
[Unit]
Description=Selenium Hub
After=syslog.target network.target


[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/bin/geckodriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -log /var/log/selenium-hub/output.log


[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### And here's another one for my selenium NODE

```
....

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/bin/geckodriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -log /var/log/selenium-node/output.log
```

#### Here's the error i get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: None
Stacktrace:
     at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries (HashMap.java:500)
     at java.util.HashMap.putAll (HashMap.java:784)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.<init> (DesiredCapabilities.java:55)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:104)
....
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:672
at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:590
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

#### Here's how i use remote.WebDriver

```
def create_driver():
    command_executor = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'  # default
    capabilities = {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'version': '',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'javascriptEnabled': 'True',
        # 'acceptSslCerts': 'False',
        # 'unexpectedAlertBehaviour': 'True',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': [
                '--disable-extensions',
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--verbose',
                '--log-path=/var/log/chromedriver-full.log',
                '--disable-impl-side-painting',
                '--memory-model=high',
                '--disk-cache-size=500000000',
                '--allow-running-insecure-content',
                '--ignore-certificate-errors',
                '--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--disk-cache-dir=null',
            ],
            # 'extensions': [],
            # 'binary': '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
            # 'minidumpPath': '/root/'
        },
        'loggingPrefs': {'driver': 'ALL', 'server': 'ALL', 'browser': 'ALL', 'performance': 'ALL'}
    }
    driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor=command_executor)
    time.sleep(5)  # Let the user actually see something!
    driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    return driver


def main():
    print("Running remote web driver test")
    driver = create_driver()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.ph")
    print(driver.current_url)
    screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('/root/test.png')
    print(screenshot)
    driver.quit()
    display.stop()
    print("Success test on remote web driver")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error while testing selenium-extras...

I think the latest version (3.4.1) of python-selenium has a bug when interacting with Selenium GRID (hub+node), while running fine when in standalone mode instead.

I worked around it using **older** python selenium:

```
pip show selenium | grep -i version
Version: 2.48.0
```

If you installed with pip, you can uninstall it first:

```
pip uninstall selenium
```

then try a different version, I tried with success with the same available from APT:

```
pip install selenium==2.48.0
```

Maybe some later versions are working, but did not try.

Bye!